# how can i open .pdf file in office word 2013(in c#) and save as it in .docx (code in c#)?

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

I want open **Pdf** file in c# codes , I want use office word 2013 (**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word**) with c# and save as word file in c#, how can I it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry but this is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: There is a lot of info missing on what you want to achieve eventually. What exactly do you mean by `open`? Do you want to show it on screen or do you just want to read the bytes of the said pdf? Did you try looking for some c# pdf-manipulation library? Are you on track on writing it on your own?

Comment: I want convert unicode persian pdf file to text, one method is open pdf in office word and save as text. but I can't a solution to open (or read) a pdf file in word interop and save as .docx. I can extract text from docx file from c# code. how can I open and save as .docx with c#?

Comment: no screen show, just read and save as in .docx.

Comment: for convert i use itextsharp & adobe, but I want use this method also.

Answer (score 3):

Give the guy a break, it is his first question and he has actually created an account with a picture an everything so I genuinely believe he is here to learn.

I have just done a quick google and it looks as though there is no native support for this, I would suggest you search for a an api to do it. I found this one which gave you code but I have no idea if it is a good framework or not, the code sample they give is a little over complicated imo.

http://www.yiigo.com/guides/csharp/how-to-pdf-convert-word.shtml

If you are genuine then Good Luck. I would recommend looking at the way other people post questions in the future, there are a lot of people on here who help people out and sometimes it is hard to sift through all of the questions where it looks like the asker is wanting people to solve their problems because they can't be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
Wrdapp= new Word.Application();

FileConverter converter=Wrdapp.FileConverters[5];

//For checking format name
converter.FormatName;

Wrdapp.Open("PDF file path",Format:converter.OpenFormat);`
```

The file will be converted if the converters are installed with office 2013 and above